# Prove that a sum of projections is a projection iff they are orthogonal, if the characteristic of the space is not $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be projections on $V$, a vector space over $F$. Why is if $\operatorname{char}F\neq2$ then $E_1+E_2$ is a projection iff $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0$ ?

Comment: You are quite right, I apologize. I have not encountered char before, nor have been taught about it, so the wording of the question confused me.

Comment: @Asaf: the LaTeX improvement may have increased readability; however, in view of mt_'s comment, LHS had turned the question from a completely wrong statement into a correct one while the LaTeX edit re-incorporated the first version.

Comment: I rolled back because I was mid way through correcting it when you edited it, i'm very grateful for the edit, but it was the original incorrect version.

Comment: LHS:Have you tried just doing a "binomial" with $E_1+E_2$, and then using the identity $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0$?

Comment: @gary: it is clear why if E1E2=E2E1=0 the statement is correct, but i'm having issue with why if E1+E2 is a projection then E1E2=E2E1=0

Comment: @Theo, LHS: Was it not possible to correct the LaTeX edit instead?

Comment: @Asaf: I'm sorry, but I have never used LaTeX before.

Comment: @LHS: If $E_1+E_2$ is a projection, then we must have $(E_1+E_2)^2=(E_1+E_2)$ then some terms must cancel out for the equality to hold.See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it this way: $E_1+E_2$ is a projection if it satisfies: $(E_1+E_2)^2=(E_1+E_2)$

(Use $E_iE_j$ to mean the composition)

1)Assume $E_1E_2=0$

We want to show that $(E_1+E_2)(E_1+E_2)=(E_1+E_2)$ This means that $E_2E_1+E_2E_2+.....=(E_1+E_2)$ Can you see the next step?

For the converse, assume $(E_1+E_2)$ is a projection, then it must satisfy $(E_1+E_2)^2=....$

Comment: Ok, so I see if E1E2=E2E1=0 as this implies E1E1+E1E2+E2E1+E2E2=E1E1+E2E2, implying (E1+E2)^2=E1+E2

But for the converse you have E1+E2 as a projection.. i'm unsure how you can show E1E2=E2E1=0

Comment: Where do we use the fact 1+1 is not equal to 0?

Comment: Actually, you're right; it seems all we need is $E_1E_2+E_2E_1=0$. Let me see...

Comment: Ok, how about this:
we have,
1. (E1+E2)^2=E1+E2 => ((E1+E2)^2)E2E1=E1E2E1+E2E1
2. E1E2+E2E1=0 => E1E2E1+E2E1=0 => E1E2E1=-E2E1

Combining 1. and 2. gives,

((E1+E2)^2)E2E1=-E2E1+E2E1=0
((E1+E2)^2)E2E1=0

Can this only always be true if E2E1=0?

Comment: For the Char2 part, I think we use that If $E_1=E_2$, then $(E+E)^2=0\neq (E+E)$, is not a projection, i.e., we want to cover the case $E_i=E_j$

Comment: Sorry.. probably being stupid here, but why is (E+E)^2=0?

Comment: No problem; I have been kind of slow myself; If we assume $E_iE_j=0$, and we have $1+1=0$, then $(E+E)^2$=$E^2+EE+EE+E^2$=$E^2+0+0+E^2=2E^2=0$

Comment: Ah ok I see, how about this, we have E1E2+E2E1=0, so we can make E1E2E1+E2E1=0 and E1E2+E1E2E1=0, if we subtract them we get E2E1-E1E2=0. Substituting into the first equation we get the desired result?

Comment: Yes, I think that works; let me double-check.

Comment: One last, or we can go to chat: there are many ways of showing $E_1E_2+E_2E_1=0$ implies that $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0$; you can, e.g., multiply by $E_2$ on the left, to get $E_2E_1E_2+E_2E_1=0$, then $(E_2E_1)(E_2+Id)=0$, and similar rewriting for $E_1E_2=0$

Comment: Thanks very much! I think this is sorted, and at any rate due to the substantial amount of algebra my tutor has set me I think I've spent enough time on this. You have been very helpful, appreciate it greatly!

Comment: No problem, LHS, glad to help.

Comment: @gary I cannot see how $E_2E_1(E_2+Id)=0$ implies $E_2E_1=0...$?

Comment: @Freeman I would appreciate if you could please explain also because I don't understand the above

Comment: @Arcane1729 That's where $\operatorname{char} F \neq 2$ enters. We can decompose $V$ as $R \oplus K$, where $R$ is the image, and $K$ the kernel of the projection $E_2$ - that works for all projections and all vector spaces, regardless of characteristic. Now you have a simple description of $E_2 + \operatorname{Id}$ - on $R$, it's multiplication by $2$, and on $K$ it's the identity. When $\operatorname{char} F \neq 2$, it follows that $E_2 + \operatorname{Id}$ is invertible. And then you can cancel the invertible $E_2 + \operatorname{Id}$ to get $E_2E_1 = 0$.

Comment: @Arcane1729 Also look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/problem-with-sum-of-projections), where the argument is given in what I consider a more elegant way (the question assumes real scalars, but what is needed for the last step is just $2X = 0 \implies X = 0$).

Answer (score 8):

Easy direction: If $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=0$, then $(E_1+E_2)^2=E_1^2+E_2^2 = E_1+E_2$.

Conversely, suppose $(E_1+E_2)^2= E_1+E_2$. Then 
$$
E_1E_2+E_2E_1 = 0 \tag{1}
$$
By multiplying both sides of (1) by $E_1$ on the left, or by $E_1$ on the right, obtain two equalities:
$$E_1 E_2+E_1E_2E_1=0,\qquad  E_1E_2E_1+E_2E_1=0$$
By subtracting these, 
$$E_1E_2-E_2E_1=0. \tag{2}$$
Adding or subtracting (1) and (2),  we get 
$$2E_1E_2=0,\qquad  2E_2E_1=0$$
Since the characteristic is not $2$, the factor $2$ can be cancelled.

(This answer is based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507796) by [Alex](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29628/alex)).