# Algebra defined by $a^2=a,b^2=b,c^2=c,(a+b+c)^2=a+b+c$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, idempotents

Let $\cal A$ be the (noncommutative) unitary $\mathbb Z$-algebra defined by three generators
$a,b,c$ and four relations $a^2=a,b^2=b,c^2=c,(a+b+c)^2=a+b+c$. Is it
true that $ab\neq 0$ in $A$ ?

This question is natural in the context of
an older [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/problem-with-sum-of-projections/525709?noredirect=1#comment3609341_525709) here on MSE.

My thoughts : The following two relations follow easily from the axioms :

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
cb &=& -(ab+ac+ba+bc+ca) \\
cab &=& ca+ab+2(ba+ac+bc)+aba+abc+aca+bac+bca \\
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$

Denote by $W$ the set of words on $a,b,c$ (they are called monomials in the algebra $\cal A$). We order $W$ with the shortlex $a<b<c$ ordering (which we denote by $\prec$).
The two relations above express $cb$ or $cab$ in terms of $\prec$-smaller monomials. Iterating those two relations and using induction on $\prec$ ,any monomial
can be transformed in $\cal A$ into a term whose monomials do not contain any
of  $aa,bb,cc,cb,cab$. Denote by $W'$ the set of all monomials satisfying
this condition. We therefore have a surjection $s : {\cal A}' \to {\cal A}$ where ${\cal A}'=\oplus_{w\in W'} {\mathbb Z}w$.

**Conjecture 1.** The mapping $s$ is bijective, in other words $W'$ is a
$\mathbb Z$-basis for $\cal A$.

Note that the action of $a$ or $b$ on $W'$ is trivial to describe : for any monomial $w\in W'$, if $w$ does not start with an $a$ then $aw$ stays in $W'$, and $aw=w$ otherwise. Similarly for $b$.

The action of $c$ is more complicated. Using the two relations in (1) 
and induction on $\prec$ again, we see that there is a unique $\mathbb Z$-linear
map $C:{\cal A}' \to {\cal A}'$ such that $C(1)=c,C(a)=ca$ and

$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
C(abw) &=& (Ca+ab+2(ba+aC+bC)+aba+abC+aCa+baC+bCa)w \ ( \ \text{if} \ bw\in W') \\
C(acw) &=& cacw \ ( \ \text{if} \ acw\in W') \\
C(bw) &=& -(ab+aC+ba+bC+Ca)w \ ( \ \text{if} \ bw\in W') \\
C(cw) &=& cw \ ( \ \text{if} \ cw\in W')
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$

Indeed, any monomial distinct from $1$ or $a$ starts with exactly one of
$ab$, $ac$, $b$ or $c$.
It is not clear however (at least to me) how to show that

**Conjecture 1 (equivalent form).** This $C$ satisfies $C^2=C$ and $(a+b+C)^2=a+b+C$.

Comment: To show that $ab \neq 0$ in $\mathcal{A}$, just observe that there is a ring homomorphism $\mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{F}_2$ sending each of $a$, $b$ and $c$ to $1$ (by the universal property). Of course, this completely sidesteps your more interesting conjectures :)

Comment: (You are aware of Bergman's "diamond lemma" paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870878900105 and the updates at https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/updates/diamond.html , right?)

Comment: (Oh, wait, your Conjecture 1 appears on page 184 of Bergman's paper...)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for the reference! I was very much aware of diamond lemma techniques in groups and semigroups, but I didn't realize they could be generalized this easily to algebras ... "All the main results in this paper are trivial" is the best first sentence ever in a mathematical paper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Conjecture 1 is indeed true.  It can be proved using diamond lemma techniques and the proof is sketched in Section 2.1 of the paper

> *Bergman, George M.*, [**The diamond lemma for ring theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90010-5), Adv. Math. 29, 178-218 (1978). [ZBL0326.16019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0326.16019).

Essentially, using the diamond lemma, it turns out to suffice to check that the two ways to reduce $ccab$ and $cabb$ using (either by first reducing $cc$ or $bb$, or by first using your identity for $cab$) are equal, and this is a straightforward computation.

(This answer was adapted from darij grinberg's comments on the question.)