# $V$ be a f.d, vector space over complex field , $P_1,...,P_n$ projection linear operators such that $P_1+...+P_n=I$ , then $P_iP_j=O,\forall i\ne j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over complex field , $P_1,...,P_n$ be projection linear operators i.e. $P_i^2=P_i$ such that $P_1+...+P_n=I$ , then is it true that $P_iP_j=O,\forall i\ne j$ ? I can prove it easily if $n=2$ ; but I don't know how to prove in general . I have tried doing by induction but no success . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/problem-with-sum-of-projections/525709#525709

Answer (score 1):

The [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of a projection $P$ is equal to the dimension of the target space $\text{Im } P$.

Denoting $p = \dim V$ you get
$$\text{tr}(P_1 + \dots + P_n) = \sum_i \dim E_i = \text{tr} I_p = p$$ where $E_i = \text{Im } P_i$. As $\mathbb C$ is of characteristic $0$, the $E_i$ are in direct sum.

For $x=x_1 + \dots +x_n \in V$ with $x_i \in E_i$, **I claim that**
$$P_i(x_1+\dots +x_n)=x_i$$
**For the proof**, first notice that
$$P_i(x_1+\dots +x_n)=y_i$$ with $y_i \in E_i$ as $\text{Im } P_i =E_i$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
0 &= I_p(x_1 + \dots +x_n)- (x_1 + \dots + x_n )\\
&=(P_1 + \dots + P_n)(x_1 + \dots +x_n)-(x_1 + \dots +x_n)\\
&= (y_1-x_1)+ \dots + (y_n-x_n)
\end{aligned}$$ as $\bigoplus_i E_i = V$, we can conclude as desired that $x_i=y_1$ for $1 \le i \le n$

based on that, you finally get $P_i P_j=0$ for all $i \neq j$.

Comment: I don't understand why $P_i(x)=x_i$ and how does the conclusion follow from there

Comment: @SaunDev That's because $P_i(x)=P_i(x_1)+P_i(x_2)+\ldots +P_i(x_n)$ and in this sum all the terms are zero except for $P_i(x_i)$ wich equals $x_i$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy : and why is all the other term $0$ ? because $x_k \in range P_k \subseteq ker P_i $ ? but that's what we are trying to prove here ... or is it for some other reason ?

Comment: @SaunDev see my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/problem-with-sum-of-projections/525709#525709

Comment: @SaunDev I added some details to answer your question.