# Prove that if $P_1, P_2$ and $P_1+P_2$ are projections, then $P_1P_2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

> Suppose that $P_1, P_2$ and $P_1+P_2$ are projections. Prove that $P_1
> P_2 = 0$.

Since $P_1+P_2$ is a projection it should satisfy $(P_1+P_2)^2 = P_1+P_2$, i.e.
$$(P_1+P_2)^2 = P_1^2 + P_2P_1 + P_1P_2 + P_2^2 = P_1 + P_2P_1 + P_1P_2 + P_2 = P_1 + P_2$$
so $P_2P_1 + P_1P_2 = 0$ or $P_1P_2 = -P_2P_1$. How can I conclude now that $P_1P_2 = 0$?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/show-that-p-i-and-sum-i-p-i-being-idempotent-implies-p-i-p-j-delta-ij?rq=1) answer your question?

Comment: @twosigma, yes, it does.

Comment: The proof therein is complicated. There is an easier way, by simply computing $(p_1 p_2)^2=-p_1p_2$. Now show that $-1$ can not be an eigenvalue of $p_1p_2$ to conclude.

Comment: Is the following okay? Clearly, since 
$P_1P_2=-P_2P_1$, pre-multiplying by $P_1$ and post-multiplying by $P_2$ yields: 
$P_1P_2=-(P_1P_2)^2 \tag {1}$
Similarly, pre-multiplying by $P_2$ and post-multiplying by $P_1$ yields: 
$(P_2P_1)^2=-P_2P_1 \implies (-P_1P_2)^2=P_1P_2 \implies (P_1P_2)^2=P_1P_2 \tag{2}$
Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $P_1P_2=0$

Comment: @Koro, I think it's correct and if you'll post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: note the stated result is False in fields of characteristic two.  Consider e.g. $P_1 = I =P_2$  with scalars in $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: In general, in a ring, if $a^2=a, b^2=b$ and $ab=-ba$, then
$$
ab=aab=a(-ba)=(-ab)a=baa=ba.
$$
Therefore, if the ring is an algebra over a field of characteristic $\ne2$, one can obtain from $ab=-ba$ and $ab=ba$ that $ab=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are elements of some operator algebra over a field $\Bbb F$ with

$\text{char} \; \Bbb F \ne 2. \tag  0$

Given that

$P_1^2 = P_1, \tag 1$

and

$P_2^2 = P_2, \tag 2$

and

$(P_1 + P_2)^2 = P_1 + P_2, \tag 3$

observe that

$P_1 + P_2 = (P_1 + P_2)^2 = P_1^2 + P_1P_2 + P_2P_1 + P_2^2 = P_1 + P_1P_2 + P_2P_1 + P_2, \tag 4$

whence

$P_1P_2 + P_2P_1 = 0; \tag 5$

left multiply this by $P_1$:

$P_1P_2 + P_1P_2P_1 = P_1^2P_2 + P_1P_2P_1 = 0; \tag 6$

right multiply (5) by $P_1$:

$P_1P_2P_1 + P_2P_1 = P_1P_2P_1 + P_2P_1^2 = 0; \tag 7$

it follows that

$P_1P_2 = -P_1P_2P_1 = P_2P_1; \tag 8$

also, from (5),

$P_1P_2 = -P_2P_1; \tag 9$

add (9) and (10):

$2P_1P_2 = P_2P_1 - P_2P_1 = 0; \tag{10}$

then by virtue of (0),

$P_1P_2 = 0, \tag{10}$

$OE\Delta$.

Observing the symmetry 'twixt $P_1$ and $P_2$ it also follows that

$P_2P_1 = 0. \tag{11}$