# Projections exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

If $P_1+P_2+\cdots+P_k=I$ and $P_i^2=P_i$ for each $i=1,...,k$ then $P_iP_j=0$ for each $i\neq j$.

I did the following
$$P_j=P_jI=P_j\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k{}P_i\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k{}P_jP_i=P_j+\displaystyle\sum_{i\neq j}^k{}P_jP_i$$

So, $\displaystyle\sum_{i\neq j}^k{}P_jP_i=0$, Since $P_i$ they are not-negative then $P_jP_i=0$ for each $i\neq j$.

Comment: In English, we write "and" - not "y".

Comment: Why should the $P_i$ be non-negative (whatever this means)?

Comment: @amsmath Well I knew because like every $P_i^2=P_i$.

Comment: Projections aren't numbers. So, this is not valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $P_i$ and $\sum_i P_i$ being idempotent implies $P_i P_j=\delta_{ij}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507796/show-that-p-i-and-sum-i-p-i-being-idempotent-implies-p-i-p-j-delta-ij)

Comment: Note: In the link, they mention that it is necessary that we're working in finite dimensions, otherwise the statement isn't true.